# Why the SimpleDraweeView of Fresco flash a second when setImageUrl again

Tags: android, fresco

I am creating a share element tranition, the shareelement SimpleDraweeView was seted original thumbnail until the higher resolution one is downloaded.
My problem is that the SimpleDraweeView flash a second after I set the URL again of higher resolution.Is it the Freso's bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you simply call 
`abstractDraweeControllerBuilder.setLowResImageRequest(...)`

and

`abstractDraweeControllerBuilder.setImageRequest(...)`.